# Renaming variables in legend in ggplot bar plot while keeping the bar order the same as well

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have three dataframes in R:

```
> df1
   zone   meangpp
1     1 5.4153407
2     2 4.2429236
3     3 4.5719178
4     4 3.1215946
5     5 4.9222054
6     6 3.0384872
7     7 1.9293729
8     8 8.9709741
9     9 7.8904906
10   10 6.6410986
11   12 5.5011823

> df2
   zone     meangpp
1     1 4.050161
2     2 7.729265
3     3 3.408220
4     4 4.884040
5     5 4.258422
6     6 2.906374
7     7 2.241984
8     8 4.703197
9     9 3.617657
10   10 2.712997
11   12 3.589406

> df3
   zone     meangpp
1     1 5.65432
2     2 8.76234
3     3 2.67676
4     4 5.63432
5     5 9.87654
6     6 3.45423
7     7 6.76745
8     8 3.45545
9     9 1.23434
10   10 2.712997
11   12 3.589406
```

I created a grouped bar plot with the following code provided by a user in my previous question.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- bind_rows("df1" = df1, "df2" = df2, "df3" = df3, .id = "groups")

my_sd <- df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  summarise(sd=sd(meangpp))

# Standard deviation
df %>% 
  left_join(my_sd) %>% 
  mutate(zone = factor(zone)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=zone, y=meangpp, fill = groups)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=zone, ymin=meangpp-sd, ymax=meangpp+sd), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  ggtitle("using standard deviation")
```

The result of the plot is shown below:

[image: barplot]

I would like to change the legend variable names `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` to `GC`, `IP`, and `CS` respectively.

I made some previous attempts, but the variable `CS` shifts up in the legend and the bar of `CS` is also shifted to first in the plot.

I would like to keep `GC`, `IP`, and `CS` in the same order in legend as shown above, not alphabetically. Additionally, I would like to keep the bars in the order shown above (`GC`, `IP`, `CS`).

Comment: you can ty to change the names beforehand `mutate(groups = forcats::fct_recode(groups, GC = "df1", ....))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add a call to `scale_fill_discrete` with a `labels =`  argument.

```
df %>% 
  left_join(my_sd) %>% 
  mutate(zone = factor(zone)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=zone, y=meangpp, fill = groups)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=zone, ymin=meangpp-sd, ymax=meangpp+sd), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("GC", "IP", "CS")) + 
  ggtitle("using standard deviation")
```

[image]

An alternative way alluded to by Roman in the comments is to recode the `group` column before plotting and then setting the factor order to control the plotting order:

```
df %>% 
  left_join(my_sd) %>% 
  mutate(groups = recode(groups, df1 = "GC", df2 = "IP", df3 = "CS")) %>%
  mutate(zone = factor(zone)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=zone, y=meangpp, fill = factor(groups, c("GC","IP","CS")))) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=zone, ymin=meangpp-sd, ymax=meangpp+sd), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  ggtitle("using standard deviation") +
  labs(fill = "groups")
```